# How do I populate a mysql workbench models inserts from a mysql script?

Tags: mysql, insert, reverse-engineering

I cannot find a function that reverse engineers a mysql create **AND** insert script and places the inserts into the tables created inside the model.

When I go to **Import->Reverse Engineer MySQL Create Script** it does not place the insert statements into the table inserts.

The only option I found that was similar was import records from an external file, but it defaults to CSV and if I change the file type to All Files it does nothing when I open a .sql file with multiple inserts inside of it.

[image: Table Inserts[1]]